# ThreadLocal value not cleared for the next thread in java

Tags: java, thread-safety, thread-local

I'm running a web service which is receiving 200 RPS at least. Based on the action, we provide root access for few operations and using the following code.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<String> rootContext = new ThreadLocal<String>();

public Optional<String> getRunner() {
    if (rootContext.get() != null) {
        return rootContext.get();
    } else {
        return getCurrentRunner();
    }
}

public void rootAccess(Runnable runnable) {
    rootContext.set("root");
    runnable.run();
    rootContext.set(null);
}
```

`getCurrentRunner()` method will return the actual caller based on the request. The problem is 1 request out of 200 requests returns `root` instead of the actual caller.

One thing I noticed is instead of using threadlocal.remove(), I'm setting that value as null. Expecting that, getRunner() `rootContext.get() != null` condition will fail and return the actual caller.

How to solve this ? Will setting `rootContext.remove()` solve this ? If yes, how ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your `rootAccess` method:

1. if the Runnable throws a RuntimeException the ThreadLocal is not removed (probably what you are seeing)
2. `rootContext.set(null);` still keeps the `ThreadLocal` instance associated with the running thread, it is better to do `rootContext.remove();`

Correcting this two points means to change `rootAccess()` to

```
public void rootAccess(Runnable runnable) {
    rootContext.set("root");
    try {
        runnable.run();
    } finally {
        rootContext.remove();
    }
}
```

---

Why is `rootContext.set(null);` generally a problem?

Each thread basically keeps a data structure similar to a `Map<ThreadLocal, ?>` where the key is your `ThreadLocal` instance (`rootContext`) and the value is the value that you associate with it through `rootContext.set(xx);`

If you call `rootContext.set(null);` then `rootContext` is still in that map and therefore each thread (from a thread pool, meaning the thread is long running) that executed this line keeps a reference to `rootContext` which in turn might prevent class unloading.

If you call `rootContext.remove();` the `rootContext` is removed from that map.